# C conflicting types error

Tags: c

```
void ListRecord(struct Product* prd)
{
    int i;
    system("cls");
    printf("%10s%20s%20s","BarcodeNumber","Name","Quantity","Price");

    for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    {
        if(prd[i].isFull=='E')
        {
            printf("\n%10s%20s%20s",prd[i].barcodeNumber,prd[i].name,prd[i].quantity,prd[i].price);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

this method gives the conflicting error for the ListRecord method but I didnt get what is the wrong things?

Comment: You miss a `%10s` in each `printf` I guess.

Comment: Using this function without putting the prototype.

Comment: I put %10s for each printf but still it is not work it give same error @pzaenger

Comment: I didnt get your point mainly ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Show a [mcve]. Something is missing in your full code and we can't tell you what it is unless you show us a complete example of your code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question.